# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from...... Document is Empty

Tags: magento-1.9, php

We have Magento 1.9.2.4 and we have an extension which uses an API Url to fetch data to supply our cart with shipping charges for customers.

When we are at checkout and we arrive at the shipping step, it tries to load the shipping rates and we receive the following error.

[image]

it states it is trying to load from a rating file located in our var/tmp dir and when i go to that folder on ftp the file is there and it shows 0 bytes in size so it is in fact empty.

Has anyone come across this error and know of ways to find out what is causing this to happen?